# browser doesn't recognize special characters

Tags: html, special-characters

Some special characters is not being recognized by browsers(chrome, firefox, ie). If I write html codes for these characters, no problem exists.

**Special Characters:**

```
var message = 'Lütfen cinsiyetinizi seçiniz.';
$('.show').html('<div>' + message + '</div>');
```

With this, I see in browser `L�tfen cinsiyetinizi se�iniz.`.

**Corresponding Html Codes:**

```
var message = 'L&uuml;tfen cinsiyetinizi se&ccedil;iniz.';
$('.show').html('<div>' + message + '</div>');
```

With this, I see what I want to see as `Lütfen cinsiyetinizi seçiniz.`.

You can test my setup in [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/saNQFQPp).

If I use a basic setup everything works fine as you can see in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bvJGb/1/) (thanks to @Pachonk)

What is the problem in my html code, any advice to solve?

Comment: Your question is about JavaScript, not jQuery. What browser are you running this code in? Can you post a minimal working example?

Comment: Where is `İ` in `Lütfen`?

Comment: I've removed the jQuery tag and edited the title of your question as jQuery is irrelevant in this case.

Comment: @j08691 - I suspect that's the crux of the problem; for whatever reason he seems to be replacing a non-matching character. I have not been able to replicate in Chrome, but this could be implementation-specific (with regards to the JS engine)

Comment: It's working fine in all browsers for me: http://jsfiddle.net/bvJGb/

Comment: @Pachonk in my local, while debugging it doesn't work. Why is so that?

Comment: Maybe it is cached? What editor are you using?

Comment: @Pachonk I use visual studio 2013 ide.

Comment: @Pachonk I published it to local IIS the same problem exists.

Comment: Do a control+u and copy/paste the results into a pastebin.

Comment: @Pachonk I couldn't replicate it, code has lots of links

Comment: You can't copy and paste source code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54326/discussion-between-serefbilge-and-pachonk).

Comment: @serefbilge, I have replied in chat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved when I added a new js file inside visual studio, and copied javascript content into it, then I deleted old js file.

The old js file was downloaded from browser. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score -1):

First, `'İ'.charCodeAt(0) === 304`. That means `&#304;` and `İ` are the same character, which has nothing to do with `ü`.

Second, `"Lütfen".replace("İ", "&#304;")` gives `"Lütfen"`, not `"Lİtfen"` nor `"L&#304;tfen"`

Then, it does differentiate `"ü"` and `"İ"`.

---

You don't need to escape those characters if you encode your document properly, e.g using UTF-8 without BOM.